# Issue with Google Maps API v3 in iOS mobile app

Tags: ios, html, google-maps, cordova, google-maps-api-3

We have an issue with Google Maps API v3 in our iOS PhoneGap app.

A little of history:
We had build a large app using Phonegap platform so the most of the app is a HTML5.
We're extensively utilizing the Google Maps API v3 in our application.
The maps are shown on at least 11 pages in our app.
The application architecture is such that on each page transition we're removing the content of the previous page (which is a DIV on the main index.html) and replace it with the content of another page and then execute the scripts that initialize page etc.

Initially we were initializing the Google Maps each time the new page was loaded through: new google.maps.Map(...); constructor.
However, we've discovered a serious side effect - a large memory leakage on each map initialization. By googling we had found that this is a known issue and Google Maps API v3 is not designed to initialize map more than one time per page and for maps to not leak the memory the page reload is necessary so browser can clean up the memory.
However, this resolution doesn't work for us because such reinitialization will break the application architecture (a single page app).

So, to prevent the memory leakage and at the same time to keep the architecture we decided to store the handle to the div that contains map and just reenter it on the page, when that page is displayed once again.
So, we're creating a single map instance for the page that needs to display the map, and when that page is displayed, we're appending the div with initialized map to the page, setting map zoom, center and triggering the resize event.

```
page.map.setZoom(14);
page.map.setCenter(coordinates);
google.maps.event.trigger(page.map, 'resize');
```

This works great for a while. The leak is gone and the map is correctly displayed, but, once again, for a while... After a couple of transitions between pages with the maps the maps start working weird - when scrolling the map the map stops refreshing and loading the images so the gray area is displayed. At the same time, the Google logo and all the other information is displayed in correct places. The markers are also displayed in correct places. When looking through the Safari Inspector we can see that the divs that should display the images are not inside the map.
So, we suspect that after DOM manipulations (e.g. when we are clearing the page content and replacing it with new content) and restoring the map, something happens to the children elements or something else happens.

Does anyone have any ideas what can we do in this situation?

NOTE: We were able to repeat the same issue in Mobile Safari, but not in desktop version of Safari or Chrome.

Below is a couple of screen shots of what happens after some time the app is used.

[image: Example 1]
[image: Example 2]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If i understand the problem correctly, a resize event needs to be triggered on pageshow. Here is an abbreviated function.

```
        $("div[id=maps]").bind("pageshow", function (e, data) {
            google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");

        });
```

Always interested in finding different solutions...http://jsfiddle.net/wptc/y6Kpb/

Comment: As I noted in my post, we're triggering the resize event when the page is shown

Comment: Right, but i have found the timing of the event to be an issue. May try moving the resize to be first thing, before zoom and center?

Comment: Any luck solving the problems you noted. Let us know if you found an answer or need additional help concerning this question.

Comment: No luck. The issue still happens. We've tried a different order of the commands and it doesn't help. Also, at some point map stops showing the markers as well.

Comment: More than that - we've back to the architecture when we recreate the map on each page (not just place the existing DIV) and the issue is still reproducible.

Comment: Been away from my desk and you may have moved on Denis. Need more specifics; still consider timing on re-size map event basis of issue.